# OpenCV: how to set alpha transparency of a pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, visualization

I have an image I am trying to segment by colouring each pixel either red green or blue. I have calculated a confidence score for each pixel and want to adjust the alpha transparency of the pixel to reflect confidence, i.e. low confidence means almost transparent. Is there a way to do this in OpenCV? If not can anyone suggest a minimally invasive library (C++)?

I have tries using a 4 channel 8-bit `Mat` as suggested by Aurellius, here is the code:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat(20,20, CV_8UC4);
    for(int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m.cols; j++){
            Vec4b& v = m.at<Vec4b>(i,j);
            v[0] = 255;
            v[1] = 0;
            v[2] = 0;
            v[3] = 0.5;
        }
    }

    imwrite("alpha.png", m);
    namedWindow("m");
    imshow("m", m);
    waitKey(0);
```

The image shown is just all blue (no transparency) and the image just fully transparent.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to accomplish this. One possible way is to access and modify each individual pixel. Assuming `image` is a four-channel, 8-bit `cv::Mat`:

```
auto& pixel = image.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j);
pixel[3] = confidence;
```

where `i` and `j` are the indices of the pixel in the image.

There are other methods that are probably more elegant, but they will depend on your current code.

**UPDATE:**
The behavior you describe is to be expected. [Apparently](http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.com/2012/10/overlay-transparent-image-in-opencv.html) `cv::imshow()` does not support transparency. This explains why your displayed image is all blue.

As for the saved image, it is important to remember that the image is of type `CV_8UC4`. That means that each channel element is stored as a `uchar`. Assigning a value of `0.5` will truncate to zero, hence the fully transparent saved image.

If your confidence is a float value in the range `[0,1]`, scale it by 255 to put it in the range supported by 8-bit images. Thus,

```
v[3] = 0.5;
```

becomes

```
v[3] = 0.5 * 255;
```

Answer (score 3):

I've also had the same problem but when was drawing transparent shapes and solved it by blending images.
I've fount this in OpenCV's documentation

```
if you want to paint semi-transparent shapes, you can paint them in a separate buffer and then blend it with the main image.
```

For this purpose I suggest you to take a look at [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) documentation article. Hope this will help.