# Draw image on matrix

Tags: android, opencv, alpha, face-detection

I have started development in openv cv on android platform. I got an issue on drawing on matrix. i have rgba Matrix and i want to draw image on that matrix. I have done some code but image is not drawn on that matrix. Help please.

my code:

```
private Mat get_template(CascadeClassifier clasificator, Rect area, int size) {
    Mat template = new Mat();
    Mat mROI = mGray.submat(area);
    MatOfRect eyes = new MatOfRect();
    Point iris = new Point();
    Mat img = null;
    Mat cokeBGR;
    Mat cokeRGBA;
    Mat m;
    Rect round = null;
    Rect eye_template = new Rect();
    clasificator.detectMultiScale(mROI, eyes, 1.15, 5,
            Objdetect.CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
                    | Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, new Size(50,50 ),
            new Size());

    Rect[] eyesArray = eyes.toArray();
    Mat vyrez;
    int radius;


    for (int i = 0; i < eyesArray.length; i++) {

        /*Toast.makeText(context, "lenght id = "+eyesArray.length, 2000).show();*/
        Rect e = eyesArray[i];
        e.x = area.x + e.x;
        e.y = area.y + e.y;
        Rect eye_only_rectangle = new Rect((int) e.tl().x,
                (int) (e.tl().y + e.height * 0.4), (int) e.width,
                (int) (e.height * 0.6));
        mROI = mGray.submat(eye_only_rectangle);
        vyrez = mRgba.submat(eye_only_rectangle);

        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmG = Core.minMaxLoc(mROI);
    //  String imgPath = "android.resource//"
        //Mat openImag = imread(Path);
        Core.circle(vyrez, mmG.minLoc, 2,new Scalar(255,255,0,-2500005),20);
        iris.x = mmG.minLoc.x + eye_only_rectangle.x;
        iris.y = mmG.minLoc.y + eye_only_rectangle.y;
        eye_template = new Rect((int) iris.x - size / 2, (int) iris.y- size / 2, size, size);

        // eye ball rectangle
        /*Core.rectangle(mRgba, eye_template.tl(), eye_template.br(),
                new Scalar(0,0, 0, 0 ), 4);
    */

        template = (mRgba.submat(eye_template)).clone();
        return template;
    }
    return template;
}
```

Comment: Why the 4th argument of the circle color is that negative?!

Comment: @Mahmood i think the fourth argument is alpha channel,this channel give me result as i want to draw transparent image on a mat, i think the more i set negative value of forth channel of scalar (Alpha) the more i gain opacity. kindly help if you can. thanks

Comment: To be frank, your code is a little hard to follow. But check these to be able to track the problem: 1) print the coordination of the rect/circle you want to draw and see whether it's in the bounds of the matrix. 2) I think the Alpha channel is in [0,255]. Change it to 0 and see what happens. You can also omit it if you don't need transparency.

Comment: yes coordinates i want to draw are correct, yes you are right about alpha channel range, i have check all possibilities regarding range thats why i set it to negative. I want transparent image drawn on mat and i also get some results but scalar colors are not very much suitable for transparency. i am acually working on eye detection and want to draw transparent image on boths eyes and i already crop and clone both eyes. Have you any idea about how to draw transparent image on some mat.

Comment: @Mahmood kindly show some code or refer any link. thanks

Comment: Check this: http://bistr-o-mathik.org/2012/06/13/simple-transparency-in-opencv and also http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/transparent-image-overlays-in-opencv and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196312/opencv-how-to-set-alpha-transparency-of-a-pixel