# How do you change the transparency of an image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image and I would like to keep the centre opaque and slowly increase the transparency of the image going towards the edges. I'm trying to do this in Python with cv2 but am not having any luck. Initial I though of creating a gaussian function in the alpha channel. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: May be [worth a read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196312/opencv-how-to-set-alpha-transparency-of-a-pixel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a C++ solution that assumes you have an RGBA image (UINT8 or UINT16)

```
void addTransparency(cv::Mat &mat)
{
    int s = min(mat.rows, mat.cols) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; ++j) {
            cv::Vec4b& rgba = mat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i, j);
            float r = sqrt( (float) (i - mat.rows/2)*(i - mat.rows/2) + (j - mat.cols/2)*(j - mat.cols/2) );
            rgba[3] = saturate_cast<uchar>( 255 * exp( - (r * r) / (2 * s * s) ) );
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)